# SQL insert query in Clipper language

Tags: foxpro, dbase, clipper, xbase

I have a clipper programme in which i have many DBF files which takes care of the data that is inserted.

I can able to convert DBF into SQL.

Now my doubt is after converting how should i use an INSERT query in my clipper language so that i should be able to insert user input data in to my SQL database ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need Clipper RDD that can handle SQL database.

Have a look at at [Mediator](http://www.otc.pl/index.asp?s=76&l=2)